# Transform {x,y,...} and {a,b,...} in to {x->a,y->b,..}

Tags: list-manipulation

How to merge two list and add `->` to it.

For instance, I have `{x,y,z,...}` and `{a,b,c,...}` (to make it clear,  `,...` means unknown length)

how to get a result in the form of `{x->a,y->b,z->c,...}`

Comment: Take a look at `MapThread`.

Comment: Specifically, `MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {l1, l2}]` works if your lists are `l1` and `l2`

Comment: @Sean Or equivalently `MapThread[Rule, {l1, l2}]`

Comment: I usually use `Thread[vars -> values]`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Answered in OP comments.*

---

```
keys = {x, y, z};
vals = {a, b, c};
```

• [`Thread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html):

```
Thread[keys -> vals]

(* {x -> a, y -> b, z -> c} *)
```

• [`MapThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html):

```
MapThread[Rule, {keys, vals}]

(* {x -> a, y -> b, z -> c} *)
```

• Possibly using [`AssociationThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AssociationThread.html):

```
AssociationThread[keys -> vals]

(* <|x -> a, y -> b, z -> c|> *)
```